# Postfix: relay but with sender's address

Tags: linux, postfix, relay

I have postfix configured now that incoming emails (catch-all) are sent immediately to a specific email on GMail. However I don't see the original sender's address in received emails.

What I am trying to do is to set up postfix that it could relay/forward all incoming emails or to a one specific address in my domain, to the same GMail address but with the original sender visible.

It is Debian 9.8.

Is it possible? How?

Comment: How have you configured this?

Answer (score 0):

For now I don't have 100% solution. All emails are redirected via GMail account but I need to look into the original text of message to extract the sender's email address. Then I can respond to the sender. But it would be very nice to find a proper=expected solution for that redirection.